# delay rendering untilthe fetching is complete

Tags: reactjs

I am using react Context and useReducer to fetch the data. I am working with front end right now. i have some problems.

this is State

```
  const initialState = {
users: [
  {
    name: "Kyaw Zin Thih",
    type: "Private University",
    subjects: ["IT", "Business"],
    phNumbers: ["111-111-111", "222-222-222"],
    about: "llorem",
    location: "loremlorem",
  },
  
],
currentProfile: {},
currentPosts: [],
```

};

Inside `users` there will be a lot of users data from database. inside the `currentProfile` there will only be the data of that the user is viewing. same for `currentPosts`. when the user leave profile page both of the state will be empty again

My UI is like that. In main page there will be containers that show some data from "users". if someone click the container router will lead to Profile page. when someone reach the ProfilePage i will use useEffect to load the data to the "currentProfile" part

```
useEffect(() => {
setcurrent(username);
return () => {
  deletecurrent();
};}, []);
const publicdata = useContext(PulicDataContext):
let { url } = useRouteMatch();


const { username } = useParams();
const {
setcurrent,
currentProfile,
currentPost,
deletecurrent,
loading,} = publicdata;

const { name, type, subjects, phNumbers, location, about } = currentProfile;
```

The Problem is that when the profile page is loaded current profile is emply until it is loaded in useEffect. So names, types and so on, they are also emply when the component load. Therefore react will only show blanks in "return" part.
how can i fix that thing.

Comment: Why don't you show some animating loader in place of the blank page?